# well using NSXMLParser the values inside an array are all set to the last entry

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser, youtube-api

I use an NSXMLParser to parse YouTube's API and I get all the content I want and put it into a class called Video. When I am writing to the class from inside **parserDidEndElement** and I end that video I write the class to an **NSMutableArray**. Then I NSLog the title of the video that was logged into the array. This is different for each video. I use the **addObject:** method to add videos to the array. However when I use **parserDidEndDocument** I use a for loop to read through the array and all of the entries have the same title value of the last object added! What is going on here?

I call this in didEndElement:

```
Video *tempVideo = [Video new];
NSString *title = @"";
tempVideo = [allVideos objectAtIndex:[allVideos count]-1];
title = tempVideo.videoTitle;
NSLog(@"1videoTitle = %@", title);
```

It returns for each element *1videoTitle = (the videos title)*

I call this in didEndDocument:

```
int i;
Video *tempVideo = [Video new];
NSString *title = @"";
for(i=0;i<[allVideos count];i++){
    tempVideo = [allVideos objectAtIndex:i];
    title = tempVideo.videoTitle;
    NSLog(@"videoTitle = %@", title);
}
```

It returns for each element *videoTitle = (the last added videos title for all 19 of the videos)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tc's answer is correct, but let me re-phrase.

You are missing a very basic detail of Objective-C.

```
Video *tempVideo = [Video new];
tempVideo = [allVideos objectAtIndex:[allVideos count]-1];
```

The first line declares a variable `tempVideo` that is a *pointer to an instance of the `Video` class* and assigns to it a reference to a freshly allocated instance of `Video` class.

The second line re-assigns `tempVideo` to be a reference to an object from the `allVideos` array.   It is not a copy of the object, but a reference to the same object in the array.   The first instance -- the one from `[Video new]` -- is effectively leaked.

What isn't shown is where and how you add the Video objects to the array.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Video * tempVideo` defines a variable called "tempVideo" which is a pointer to a video.
2. `[Video new]` creates a new video.
3. `tempVideo = [allVideos objectAtIndex:[allVideos count]-1];` overwrites your pointer (leaking the video created in step 2).

It helps if you understand the difference between a value and a reference, but that's beyond the scope of this answer. Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell what's going on, but I suspect that you're repeatedly adding (pointers to) the same video object to the array.

Comment: Yes, I have one video class that I use for all videos. How would I have different classes of video work in my app?

Comment: Could I copy the object into the array and then keep using it for the parser?