# Create a copy of a NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, nsarray

How do I take a NSObject that I have set all the attributes of and then copy that into another block of memory that an array can use so I can re use the original one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you don't.

If you want to put the object in an array and then create a new object, do exactly that;  `addObject:` to the array and `alloc/init` a new one.

If you are asking how you copy an object into, say, a random `malloc()` block somewhere -- say, in the middle of an array -- then that is a very different issue.   It *can* technically be done, but basically no one does so as the frameworks and runtime aren't designed for that.

Without knowing more about your specific needs, it is impossible to go into more detail.

Comment: Here is a thread that I started that tc helped me out with but didnt help me all the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697072/well-using-nsxmlparser-the-values-inside-an-array-are-all-set-to-the-last-entry

Comment: OK -- I see what your real question is.

Comment: I figured it all out now, but now I am leaking a date object.

Answer (score 7):

Making a copy of an object is done by sending it the `copy` message. This only works on instances of classes that implement the `NSCopying` protocol.

Read [Implementing Copy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html) for a good overview. Then read [Implementing NSCopying Considered Harmful](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439) for some more background info.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question;  he wants to byte-copy the object into an array and then re-use the original.

Comment: This does answer the question as the OP isn't specific about "byte-copy". This seems to be the [updated documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/CopyFunctions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001149-CJBEJBHH) on copying (which is strange given that the [latest revision](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/RevisionHistory.html) supposedly predates this answer).